# unix txt file formatting for particular field

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

separated text file `file1.dat` with below content. I wanted to change the 3rd column by appending `$COL` to each of the `#`-separated text strings in that column.

I would like to to this for each line and save the file with same name.

Can someone help on this?

Sample input

```
name|class|colors|age|email
abc|xyz|#orange#green#pink#blue|16|abc@gmail.com
pqr|xyz|#orange#green#pink#blue|20|pqr@gmail.com
```

Desired output

```
name|class|colors|age|email
abc|xyz|#orange$COL#green$COL#pink$COL#blue$COL|16|abc@gmail.com
pqr|xyz|#orange$COL#green$COL#pink$COL#blue$COL|20|pqr@gmail.com
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind editing your post to explain what you already tried, and where you ran into problems? Could you also indicate what OS flavor and version you are using, as that will give information on what tools (in which versions) are at your disposal. Will any tool be ok, or just `awk` and `sed`? Dou you want to include the _literal string_ `$COL` or is this a shell variable whose _content_ you want to insert?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you want to add `$COL` to the end of every string on the line that starts with `#`. For this simple case, you can simply do:

```
$ sed -E 's/(#[^#|]*)/\1$COL/g' file
name|class|colors|age|email
abc|xyz|#orange$COL#green$COL#pink$COL#blue$COL|16|abc@gmail.com
pqr|xyz|#orange$COL#green$COL#pink$COL#blue$COL|20|pqr@gmail.com
```

Or, if your `sed` doesn't support `-E`:

```
sed 's/\(#[^#|]*\)/\1$COL/g' file
```

And you can use `-i` to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i -E 's/(#[^#|]*)/\1$COL/g' file
```

For the more general case, to replace add `$COL` to `#`-separated strings but only on the 3rd `|`-separated field, you can do:

```
$ awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' 'NR>1{gsub(/#[^#|]*/,"&$COL",$3)}1' file 
name|class|colors|age|email
abc|xyz|#orange$COL#green$COL#pink$COL#blue$COL|16|abc@gmail.com
pqr|xyz|#orange$COL#green$COL#pink$COL#blue$COL|20|pqr@gmail.com
```

With newer versions of GNU `awk`, you can use `-i inplace` to edit the file in place:

```
awk -iinplace -F'|' -vOFS='|' 'NR>1{gsub(/#[^#|]*/,"&$COL",$3)}1'
```

Finally, just for fun, you can also use Perl to change all `#`-defiend strings:

```
perl -pe 's/(#[^#|]+)/$1\$COL/g' file
```

or, to only do it on the 3rd column:

```
perl -F'\|' -lane '$F[2]=~s/(#[^#|]+)/$1\$COL/g; print join "|",@F' file
```

or, to only do it on the 3rd column and skip the 1st line:

```
perl -F'\|' -lane '$F[2]=~s/(#[^#|]+)/$1\$COL/g if $.>1; print join "|",@F' file
```

In both cases, you can use `-i` to edit the file in place.

Comment: this is working but putting control M characters along with in the header
sed -i -E 's/(#[^#|]*)/\1$COL/g' file

below one with awk is working perfectly as wanted to edit 3rd column only, but since GNU is not available i am not able to do inplace edit with awk
awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' 'NR>1{gsub(/#[^#|]*/,"&$COL",$3)}1' file

Comment: @ashishgoyal this wouldn't add `^M`. It sounds like your file was edited on Windows and has windows line endings. Does it work as expected if you first run `dos2unix file` and then the commands I gave?